# Calling soap function with parameters in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I'm new to soap and I have this task where I need to send request and receive response. However I get soap fault exception stating missing or invalid parameters. I've been looking at the solution for hours but none have worked for me.

I know my parameters aren't working but I am unaware of how to send them. I've wrapper them in an array as few solutions stated that but it hasn't worked for me.

I would really appreciate if you could look at my situation and help me solve understand the situation.

If I connect with SOAP using SoapClient, and get functions and types I get the following:

SOAP FUNCTIONS:

```
array (
        [0] => agentBalanceResult getAgentBalance(authorizationData $requesterAuthentication, agentIdentifier $targetAgent, string $productId,   string $requestTag)
)

<?php
```

SOAP TYPES:

```
Array
(
[0] => struct authorizationData {
              aliasCategory aliasCategory;
              string aliasName;
              string aliasPassword;
              long mvnoId;
       }

[1] => struct agentIdentifier {
              long actorId;
              aliasCategory aliasCategory;
              string aliasName;
              long mvnoId;
       }
)
```

My Class that sends the request

```
class SendRequest {

private $client;

public function __construct(){

    $this->client = new SoapClient(
                                    "myurl",
                                    [
                                        'location' => 'myurl'
                                    ]
                    );

}

public function sendRequestWithData(){

    //test parameters
    $testParameters = [

        "authorizationData" => [
            "aliasCategory" => "*****",
            "aliasName" => "*****",
            "aliasPassword" => "*****",
            "mvnoId" => "*****"
        ],

        "agentIdentifier" => [
            "actorId" => *****,
            "aliasName" => "*****",
            "aliasCategory" => "*****",
            "mvnoId" => "*****"
        ],

        "productId" => "*****",
        "requestTag" => "*****"

    ];

    $this->client->getAgentBalance($testParameters);

}

}

$send = new SendRequest;
$send->sendRequestWithData();

// throws Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Server] Missing or invalid SOAP request parameters in
```

Answer (score 0):

My best advice is to use a WSDL to php generator. It will generate classes that match the required parameters for constructing the request and you'll have the classes that match the response. In addition you'll have the classes to send the request so yo won't wonder what parameters are required if you use a correct IDE with auto completion such as Eclipse PDT.
I can't propose you anything else that the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project to generate the classes that match the SoapClient WSDL structs and services.